# How to fetch image from DB in php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to fetch image from DB(MYSQl)

I have `ConfigDB.php` where all querys are located. 
I'm fetching data from other fields using `value=` and then `echo` field
In DB I have `name` and image itself is on folder uploads.

Any suggestion how to fetch image, since I have `edit.php`, `addpost.php`, `configDB.php` and `index.php`

I saw a lot of examples but they are done with single page on `index.php`.

Currently I'm fetching 5 fields, but can't image.

This is current code from `edit.php`

I have tried solutions with while loop, but it shows nothing.

```
 <p><label>Title</label><br/>
<input class="form-control form-control-lg" type="text" placeholder="Title" name="Title" value="<?php echo $Title; ?>"></p>
</div>


<div class="col-2"></div>
<div class="col-4">

    <label>Featured Image</label><br/>
<div style="height:200px;width:100px">
   <!-- <img src="uploads/car.jpg"> -->
</div>
```

Is there a way to fetch image from DB without adding while loop in the `edit.php` file?

configDB code:

//Show POST

```
if (isset($_GET['edit'])) {
    $id = $_GET['edit'];
    $update = true;
    $result= mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id= $id");
    $result = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $Title =$result['Title'];
    $Date = $result['Date'];
    $Content = $result['Content'];
    $Image = $result['Image'];
```

}

Comment: post the content of `ConfigDB.php` after being obscured your database credentials.

Comment: Update your example with more code, loop and db structure, please.

Comment: There is show post code that currently should get me all data fetch from DB. It is set as edit because name on button was set like that, but it doesn't matter. Through the icon I'm calling this code, so it opens singlepost page and it should fetch all data, but there is no image.

Comment: @MujoRamic What exactly is saved inside the `Image` column? How do you work with the variable `$Image`? What do you do with it after you have read the data from MySQL? Please [edit] your question to include all relevant source code.

Answer (score 0):

You can save a path from a Image in your Database...
Echo the path in the SRC like this:

```
<img src="<?php echo $mysql_row['your_src_key']; ?>">
```

your_src_key => Path to your Image like "assets/img/picture.png" (Your SQL Key of the Table for your Value)

Comment: I have tried to put column there in the brackets but still nothing :(

Comment: How do you fetch the database?

Comment: How do you mean? I was fetching using buttons, isset function, method get, and then just echo value into input field such as date, title content and so on. Everything is working beside image, no matter what code I do it shows broken image.

Answer (score 0):

Our Database View:

table_images
 - id
 - path

Now lets fetch the Database row...

```
<?php
  $sql = mysqli_connect("host", "user", "password", "database");
  $row = mysqli_fetch_row($sql->query("SELECT * FROM table_images WHERE id = 
  'image_id'"));
?> 
<img src="<?php echo $row['path']; ?>">
```

You need to fetch the MySQL/SQL Query response before you can use it!

Comment: I did that. Still nothing.

Comment: You should merge these into one answer.

Comment: @MujoRamic please send me / us your Code and Table.